# SSH login as root in Azure

Tags: linux, azure, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I am trying to enable SSH login as root in a Linux VM running on Microsoft Azure. The VM is based on the Oracle Linux 6.4 image from Azure Marketplace.

I would like to be able to SSH into the VM as user root, using public certificate authentication. I need the direct root login (as opposed to using sudo) because I am trying to perform an automated deployment of software to the Azure VM, using rsync connecting to the target as root.

Here is what I tried:

1. I have the public key in the authorized_keys file, and I am able to log in without a password as a regular user - but not root.
2. I have the same authorized_keys file that worked with the regular user copied to /root/.ssh . The directories /root and /root/.ssh, and the file authorized_keys are all owned by root and not writable by anyone else.
3. I have set

   ```
   PermitRootLogin yes
   ```

   in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, then restarted sshd (and rebooted the VM).
4. When connecting as root, I get the "Server refused our key" message. I successfully enabled SSH login as root with password authentication, and was able to log in as root with a password:

   ```
   Using username "root".
   Server refused our key
   Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
   Password:
   [root@myazureserver ~]#
   ```
5. I have started a second instance of sshd in debug mode, on a different port:

   ```
   [root@myazureserver ~]# /usr/sbin/sshd -Dd -p 2020
   debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_5.3p1
   debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
   debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
   debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
   debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
   debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
   debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-Dd'
   debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-p'
   debug1: rexec_argv[3]='2020'
   Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
   debug1: Bind to port 2020 on 0.0.0.0.
   Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2020.
   debug1: Bind to port 2020 on ::.
   Server listening on :: port 2020.
   ```

   When I connect to the debug instance of sshd (on port 2020), I am able to log in as root without a password - it accepts the public key!
6. Instead of using PuTTY on Windows as the SSH client, I tried using the ssh command on the same VM (when logged in as a regular user). I was able to log in via SSH from one regular user account to another without a password, but I was not able to log into the root account from the regular account. Here is the output of ssh running in debug mode, connecting as root:

   ```
   [oracle@myazureserver ~]$ ssh -vvv root@myazureserver
   OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
   debug1: Applying options for *
   debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
   debug1: Connecting to myazureserver [10.0.0.4] port 22.
   debug1: Connection established.
   debug1: identity file /home/oracle/.ssh/identity type -1
   debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa.
   debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
   debug3: key_read: missing keytype
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   ...
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
   debug3: key_read: missing keytype
   debug1: identity file /home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
   debug1: identity file /home/oracle/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
   debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
   debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
   debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
   debug3: Wrote 792 bytes for a total of 813
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
   debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
   debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
   debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
   debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
   debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 837
   debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 128/256
   debug2: bits set: 512/1024
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
   debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 981
   debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/oracle/.ssh/known_hosts
   debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
   debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/oracle/.ssh/known_hosts
   debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
   debug1: Host 'myazureserver' is known and matches the RSA host key.
   debug1: Found key in /home/oracle/.ssh/known_hosts:1
   debug2: bits set: 507/1024
   debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
   debug2: kex_derive_keys
   debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
   debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 997
   debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
   debug3: Wrote 48 bytes for a total of 1045
   debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
   debug2: key: /home/oracle/.ssh/identity ((nil))
   debug2: key: /home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f81f3a5dd70)
   debug2: key: /home/oracle/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
   debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 1109
   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
   debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
   debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
   debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
   debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
   debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
   debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
   debug1: No valid Key exchange context
   debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
   debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
   debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
   debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
   debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
   debug3: Trying to reverse map address 10.0.0.4.
   debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
   Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_54321' not found

   debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
   Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_54321' not found

   debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


   debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
   Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_54321' not found

   debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
   debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
   debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
   debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
   debug1: Trying private key: /home/oracle/.ssh/identity
   debug3: no such identity: /home/oracle/.ssh/identity
   debug1: Offering public key: /home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa
   debug3: send_pubkey_test
   debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
   debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1477
   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
   debug1: Trying private key: /home/oracle/.ssh/id_dsa
   debug3: no such identity: /home/oracle/.ssh/id_dsa
   debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
   debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
   debug3: remaining preferred: password
   debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
   debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
   debug2: userauth_kbdint
   debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
   debug3: Wrote 96 bytes for a total of 1573
   debug2: input_userauth_info_req
   debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
   Password:
   ```

   and here is the output of ssh connecting as a regular user:

   ```
   [oracle@myazureserver ~]$ ssh -vvv jziabick@myazureserver
   OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
   debug1: Applying options for *
   debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
   debug1: Connecting to myazureserver [10.0.0.4] port 22.
   debug1: Connection established.
   debug1: identity file /home/oracle/.ssh/identity type -1
   debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa.
   debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
   debug3: key_read: missing keytype
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   ...
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
   debug3: key_read: missing keytype
   debug1: identity file /home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
   debug1: identity file /home/oracle/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
   debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
   debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
   debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
   debug3: Wrote 792 bytes for a total of 813
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
   debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
   debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
   debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
   debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
   debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 837
   debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 119/256
   debug2: bits set: 535/1024
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
   debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 981
   debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/oracle/.ssh/known_hosts
   debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
   debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/oracle/.ssh/known_hosts
   debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
   debug1: Host 'myazureserver' is known and matches the RSA host key.
   debug1: Found key in /home/oracle/.ssh/known_hosts:1
   debug2: bits set: 529/1024
   debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
   debug2: kex_derive_keys
   debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
   debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 997
   debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
   debug3: Wrote 48 bytes for a total of 1045
   debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
   debug2: key: /home/oracle/.ssh/identity ((nil))
   debug2: key: /home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f2ae500fd70)
   debug2: key: /home/oracle/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
   debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 1109
   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
   debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
   debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
   debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
   debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
   debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
   debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
   debug1: No valid Key exchange context
   debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
   debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
   debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
   debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
   debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
   debug3: Trying to reverse map address 10.0.0.4.
   debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
   Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_54321' not found

   debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
   Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_54321' not found

   debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


   debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
   Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_54321' not found

   debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
   debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
   debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
   debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
   debug1: Trying private key: /home/oracle/.ssh/identity
   debug3: no such identity: /home/oracle/.ssh/identity
   debug1: Offering public key: /home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa
   debug3: send_pubkey_test
   debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
   debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1477
   debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
   debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: SHA1 fp b6:aa:fd:7b:bf:d2:99:78:48:38:cc:9e:b0:26:05:dc:1c:4e:83:35
   debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
   debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
   debug3: Wrote 640 bytes for a total of 2117
   debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
   debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
   debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
   debug2: channel 0: send open
   debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
   debug1: Entering interactive session.
   debug3: Wrote 128 bytes for a total of 2245
   debug2: callback start
   debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
   debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
   debug1: Sending environment.
   debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
   debug3: Ignored env SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED
   debug3: Ignored env TERM
   debug3: Ignored env SHELL
   debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE
   debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
   debug3: Ignored env SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE
   debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
   debug3: Ignored env USER
   debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
   debug3: Ignored env MAIL
   debug3: Ignored env PATH
   debug3: Ignored env PWD
   debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
   debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
   debug3: Ignored env SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED
   debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL
   debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
   debug3: Ignored env HOME
   debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
   debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
   debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
   debug3: Ignored env G_BROKEN_FILENAMES
   debug3: Ignored env _
   debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
   debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
   debug2: callback done
   debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
   debug3: Wrote 448 bytes for a total of 2693
   debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
   debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
   debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
   debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
   debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
   ```

*Edit - additional log file info below.* In /var/log/secure, I see this for successful login:

```
Mar 17 18:55:09 myazureserver sshd[1196]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Mar 17 19:08:18 myazureserver sshd[1383]: Accepted publickey for jziabick from xx.xx.xx.xx port 53533 ssh2
Mar 17 19:08:19 myazureserver sshd[1383]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user jziabick by (uid=0)
```

while for unsuccessful login (as root) I see in /var/log/secure

```
Mar 18 10:52:24 myazureserver sshd[1992]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Mar 18 10:53:02 myazureserver sshd[1997]: Received disconnect from xx.xx.xx.xx: 14: No supported authentication methods available
```

In /var/log/audit/audit.log I found (for unsuccessful login as root):

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1458311548.677:733): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=1948 comm="sshd" name="authorized_keys" dev=sda3 ino=259748 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1458311548.677:733): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=7f8c6621d470 a1=800 a2=1 a3=4 items=0 ppid=1196 pid=1948 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="sshd" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1458311548.679:734): user pid=1948 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=pubkey acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=xx.xx.xx.xx terminal=ssh res=failed'
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1458311668.148:735): user pid=1950 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:authentication acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=c-xx-xx-xx-xx.hsd1.il.comcast.net addr=xx.xx.xx.xx terminal=ssh res=failed'
```

What am I missing? I have done the setup of SSH with public key authentication many times on Oracle Linux (including login as root). This must be something that is specific to Azure configuration.

Comment: What can you see in the logs/audit on server?

Comment: @Jakuje, which log files should I be looking at? I edited the question and provided snippets from /var/log/secure and /var/log/audit/audit.log. I had to shorten the debug output to fit in the 30,000 character limit for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can blame SELinux. You have mislabeled `authorized_keys` file (and may be other files too).

> type=AVC msg=audit(1458311548.677:733): avc:  *denied  { read }* for  pid=1948 comm="sshd" name="authorized_keys" dev=sda3 ino=259748 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 *tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0* tclass=file

Safe solution would be to relabel `/root/`:

```
restorecon -rf /root/
```

or if it would not help, just fix the label for that specific file:

```
chcon -t ssh_home_t /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

This should do that. If not, please update the question with current results (`AVC` messages from audit are usually useful).

Comment: thank you for a quick and accurate answer! I can confirm that SELinux was the problem. I switched SELinux from `enforcing` to `permissive` in `/etc/selinux/config`, and after a reboot I was able to log in as root, authenticated with public key.

Comment: Don't do that. SELinux is there for a good reasons. Rather try to fix the issues with the labels as advised then turning it off.

Comment: thank you for a quick and accurate answer! I can confirm that SELinux was the problem. I switched SELinux from `enforcing` to `permissive` in `/etc/selinux/config`, and after a reboot I was able to log in as root, authenticated with public key.

I tried to relabel `/root/` with

    restorecon -rf /root/

and it did not help. It may be part of the Azure setup to protect the `authorized_keys` file with SELinux.

When I initially created the `/root/.ssh/authorized_users` file, I probably manually created the `.ssh` directory and copied the `authorized_users` file from my own home dir.

Comment: The second suggestion, `chcon -t ssh_home_t /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, worked for me - thank you!

I know very little about SELinux, will need to read up.

Comment: Sure. Glad to help. There is tick on the left that marks this answer as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you've found your solution, perhaps this will help someone else.

I was unable to SFTP into an Azure Ubuntu VM as root. WinSCP failed to connect with this error:

[image: Received too large (1349281121 B) SFTP packet. Max supported packet size is 1024000 B. The error is typically caused by message printed from startup script (like .profile). The message may start with "Plea". Cannot initialize SFTP protocol. Is the host running an SFTP server?]

The solution was to remove the following from `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys`:

`no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="echo 'Please login as the user "exampleadmin" rather than the user "root".';echo;sleep 10;exit 142" ssh-rsa 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`